# Using Saint Peter to Make Volkshalle a Reality

Tags: architecture, construction

If Albert Speer had had his way, the Volkshalle would have been the largest dome in human existence.  It would have been 950 feet tall and 820 wide.

[image]

Reasons as to why this structure never made it past the drawing board vary, the most practical being that Germany or more specifically its designated location in Berlin does not have the right kind of soil for such a monstrosity.

Even if we disregard poor soil content, there are still problems as to building Volkshalle.  The only way to make Volkshalle a reality is to look at two different domes found in downtown Rome:

[image]

The Pantheon, a dome that is 142 feet tall and wide.

[image]

Saint Peter's Basilica, 500 feet wide and over 100 tall.

The domes were built almost a thousand years apart, yet both stand the test of time.  How?  What features of engineering are the key to their longevity?  And would those same features apply for Volkshalle?  And what tweaks should be needed to make sure that the breathing and sweating of 150,000 occupants don't result in turning this dome into an enormous rain gauge?

Comment: The whole of Germany/Austria/Former Prussia doesn't have the soil for this? Wouldn't that mean that *no place* has the soil for this?

Comment: I think that mostly, Hitler didn't have the manpower and money to build while waging a war.

Comment: The OP is referring to the geology of Berlin, since that is where the hall was to have been built.

Comment: What about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_Farm_Center)?  Point is, within 20 years after the war it was possible to do "modern" engineering and construction.

Comment: I'm actually not sure what you're asking. Do you want an illustration of the common points between the pantheon and St-Peter's basilica in term of mechanical engineering? And explanation on how to build the Volkshalle? Something else?

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin  How can my questions not already be clear?

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin, looks clear enough to me -- "is there any reason we can't build a big fat tall dome?"